# Loading large SQL dataset to PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to load a large dataset of about 700M rows from Google Cloud SQL into PySpark which I'm using on DataProc with Zeppelin. Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do

```
%pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext, sql
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

jdbcDriver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
jdbcUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://%s:3307/%s?user=%s&password=%s' % (CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE_IP, CLOUDSQL_DB_NAME, CLOUDSQL_USER, CLOUDSQL_PWD)

df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url =jdbcUrl,
                                   driver=jdbcDriver,
                                   dbtable='Table',
                                   partitionColumn = 'appid',
                                   lowerBound = '1',
                                   upperBound = '324830',
                                   numPartitions = '10',
                                   user=CLOUDSQL_USER,
                                   password=CLOUDSQL_PWD).load()
```

When I execute it, after 8-10 minutes, it fails. Here is the (as far as I can tell) the main part:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o218.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3
in stage 2.0 (TID 11, ykog-dataproc-v2-w-3.c.decent-essence-135923.internal): 
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 25 exited caused by one of the running
tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: 
container_1481727498237_0006_01_000026 on host: ykog-dataproc-v2-w-3.c.decent-essence-135923.internal. 
Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
Killed by external signal
```

I think the problem is that it tries to fit everything into memory, which will run out. Is there a way to set `pyspark.StorageLevel` or what is the correct way to load large datasets from SQL to PySpark?

Comment: did this happen after the line you gave or after some more lines? dataframe is lazy by definition so it doesn't really load it to memory until you perform an action (e.g. show). If this happens without an action then this is probably a connection issue to the database. Make sure you can connect to the database from both driver and workers (without spark).